# Invalid Characters from XML string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I receive a an xml string from third party. The xml string contains invalid characters like & and '. I am trying to put it in dataset (ASP.NET). it throws error. Can anyone pls help.

Comment: Invalid characters in xml string..<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Customers>
<Customer>.  Company Name has invalid character &
<CustomerID>BLAUS</CustomerID>
<CompanyName>Blauer See Delikatessen</CompanyName>
<ContactName>Hanna Moos</ContactName>
<Region>test<ing</Region>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<CustomerID>SPLIR</CustomerID>
<CompanyName>Split Rail Beer & Ale</CompanyName>
<ContactName>Art raunschweiger</ContactName>
<Region>WY</Region>
</Customer>
</Customers>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell/ask the third party to provide valid XML.

Interoperability standards don't count for much when they aren't adhered to. If they are passing you invalid characters today, what's to stop them from passing mismatched nodes tomorrow? or no tags at all?

If there is no standard, then there are an endless number of scenarios for which you might need to code around.

That said, you can:

- Ensure that it is not a problem in **your** code (post code if you want specifics).
- Create a configurable list of known find/replace scenarios and pre-process your input "XML" string.
- If data integrity isn't important (personally, I think it always is), you can load your data into an HTML parser, which will be far more forgiving and allow XML DOM-like document access.

Per the OP's comment, here is a very, very simple example of a somewhat configurable find/replace.

```
public string PreProcessXml( string xml )
{
    // this list could be read from a config file

    List<Tuple<string, string>> replacements = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    // Important: if there are VALID uses of an ampersand in your document, 
    // this may invalidate them! Perform a more elaborate check using a 
    // regex, or ensure that there are no valid entities already in the document.
    replacements.Add( new Tuple<string, string>( "&", "&amp;" ) );

    replacements.Add( new Tuple<string, string>( "\"", "&quot;" ) );
    replacements.Add( new Tuple<string, string>( "\'", "&apos;" ) );

    foreach( var replacement in replacements )
    {
        xml = xml .Replace( replacement.Item1, replacement.Item2 );
    }

     return xml;
}
```

Comment: tried System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xmlString); It removed "<" and ">" of the xml nodes also.. is there a work around with it.. thanks..

Comment: @srikanth - System.SecurityElement.Escape is documented to perform 5 character replacements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(v=VS.100).aspx. Manually do a string replace for the 3 that you need, and omit the two that escape the tag characters.

Comment: +1 Most important: Demand the third party to provide well-formed XML - everything else is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The Best way to export data using xml is

```
<![CDATA[Your data goes here.]]>
```

But as you're using third party xml, Please try using this [post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316063) in order to handle special chanracter in xml.